# HTML/CSS: padding with image link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, padding

I've built a minimal example for the following problem: If I link an image, there is a small padding at its bottom although the padding of the link and image element is set to zero. I've applied a green background color to make the padding visible. So, where does the padding come from? I tested it with Safari 11 and Firefox 58.

Thank you in advance!

```css
#link {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

#image {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="index.html"><img id="image" src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" ></a>
<img id="image" src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/">
```

result:
[browser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiJIX.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

try it with `font-size:0`

```css
#link {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: green;
   font-size:0;
}

#image {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="index.html"><img id="image" src="img/test.jpg"></a><img id="image" src="img/test.jpg">
```

Comment: Works, but breaks the page that I'm working on, which is based on relative sizes in em. Thanks nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `vertical-align: top;` to the image, this will fix it. The reason for what you describe is that the image as an inline element otherwise is aligned at the baseline, and the space below the baseline remains visible. Aligning it to the top will fill the whole parent element.

```css
#link {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: green;
}

#image {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <a id="link" href="index.html"><img id="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x30/fb6"></a>
   <img id="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x30/fb6">
</body>
```